# std::function pointer to member function taking rvalue arguement MSVC2010 SP1

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, std-function, stdbind

I would like to create a std::function bound to a member function taking a rvalue argument. Here is my attempt which does not compile ("xxfunction(154): error C2664: ... You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference" among others).

```
    class C
    {
    public:
        void F(std::string &&s)
        {
                //do something with s
        }
        C(){}
    };
    C c;
    std::function<void(std::string&&)> pF = std::bind(&C::F,&c,std::placeholders::_1);
    //somewhere far far away
    pF(std::string("test"));
```

I did some reading and I think it has to do with std::function no using perfect forwarding but I cant figure out how to get it to work.

Edit:

```
std::function<void(std::string&)> pF = [&c](std::string&in){c.F(std::move(in));};
```

This is a semi viable work around but it is not perfect because calling pF will work with an lvalue now and move it anyway.

```
std::string s("test");
pF(s);
auto other = s; //oops
```

Comment: Your code without changing compiled well by GCC - http://liveworkspace.org/code/49qBgA$3 - maybe it's bug/feature of your compiler ?

Comment: clang 3.0 and gcc 4.7.2 both compile your code without complaining, this might be MSVC-specific. Which version are you using?

Comment: Why did you use l-value refs in your lambda?

Comment: @ArneMertz because with Rvalue refs I get the same errors as with bind

Comment: MSVC10 is not fully standard-compliant wrt r-value refs and lambdas and `std::function` implementation. So I guess there's nothing you can do but upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your `std::bind` implementation does not support perfect forwarding via placeholders, but since you have C++11 and `std::bind` is ugly anyways, use lambdas:

```
std::function<void(std::string&&)> pF 
  = [&c](std::string&& str)
{ 
  c.F(std::move(str)); 
};
```

**Edit:**

*Note*: Although accepted, this answer is not a solution to the problem at hand, because it is not `std::bind` but MSVC10's `std::function` implementation that is flawed. However, the suggestion has led to a workaround and therefore was accepted by [PorkyBrain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893819/porkybrain).

Comment: Then can @PorkyBrain post his actual solution as an answer and accept _that_, please?